# How to run a SpringApplication with AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have a SpringApplication that runs fine with the default ApplicationContext, but we have a scenario in which we need to refresh the context and the default context does not allow us to do this.  I've update our main Application class to look like this:

```
// package and import lines not shown here but are included in original source

@ComponentScan("edge")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setApplicationContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
```

With this code as it is, calling app.run(args) results in the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.registerApplicationEventMulticaster(EventPublishingRunListener.java:70)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
at edge.server.Application.main(Application.java:43)
```

Stepping through SpringApplication.run(), I noticed that the context's BeanFactory is null.  If I remove the line `app.setApplicationContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class)`, thereby setting the application to use the default context, the code runs up until the point where we call refresh().  That call results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once
```

Has anyone used AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext in a SpringApplication in the manner I've described and had it work?  If so, do you have any suggestions for getting this to work?  I've tried looking for ways to create the BeanFactory manually prior to calling app.run(), but there does not appear to be any public methods for doing that.  Thanks in advance for any help provided!

**Edit for clarification:**

Thanks for the comments and answers thus far.  I should have been more explicit in my original post regarding the scenario that requires refreshing the ApplicationContext and my attempt at using AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.  We have some code that runs after the server starts up that we're using for backup and restore purposes, which involves modifying the content of the JpaRepositories that we're using.  My understanding is that after running this code, we need to refresh the ApplicationContext in order to call all of our init methods again.

Attempting to do this with the default context class (AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext, a subclass of GenericApplicationContext) throws the IllegalStateException that I had mentioned before (`GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once`).  That exception is what prompted my attempt to explicitly set the context to AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, which is a subclass of AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.  My assumption was that I needed the application to use an AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext in order to make multiple calls to the refresh method successfully.  Is there a way to get the code I have above to work, or is there some alternative approach I should be taking that would allow us to refresh the context multiple times?

Comment: Code smell:  your entire application does not to have transaction management, async, or scheduling.  Also, this isn't a configuration class, so there's really no need for that their either.  (It also doesn't really hurt it.)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  I should have been more explicit in my original post regarding what my exact question was.  Please see the clarification edit at the end of the post.  Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you would need to refresh the context is imho a clear sign that your solution is flawed. Why would you need to refresh the context?

Comment: My original thought was that I needed to re-run the init methods in our components, hence the reason I thought a refresh was required.  After messing with the code a bit, I was able to get our solution to work without requiring a refresh.  Thanks again for the input.

Comment: And the solution was? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot which already does this for you, you are just making it overly complex. Change your class to the following.

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And make sure it is in the `edge` package and make sure you have the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency which enables a web application. There is no need to mess around with the context class yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  I should have been more explicit in my original post regarding what my exact question was.  Please see the clarification edit at the end of the post.  Thanks!